# Does PHP cURL extension in version 7.4.2 support cURL with HTTP/3

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, quic, http3

Can I curl a website that supports HTTP/3, with curl, using HTTP/3 instead of HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0. Is this possible? If so, how to do this?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/curl/curl/wiki/HTTP3 or https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/08/05/first-http-3-with-curl/ (both at the top of Google results for "curl http/3")?

Comment: I see that it is introduced to curl, but how do I use it in PHP? What is the curl option I should use to enable it?

Comment: Here is an code example (I don't guarantee if this will work): https://gist.github.com/bagder/a88d3bedc8ecb69d19aeb542fa538e9b.

You need to make sure, that your curl version is build with HTTP3 support!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is indeed possible to get going but you need tweaks and manual hands-on to make it work:

1. Make sure your PHP uses a libcurl built to support [HTTP/3](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/HTTP3.md)
2. Provide the necessary HTTP3 symbol for your PHP program, perhaps like the example below (as CURL/PHP itself doesn't know about HTTP/3 yet)
3. Make sure that the QUIC/h3 libraries you build curl to use support the same HTTP/3 draft version as the test server you intend to try out
4. HTTP/3 and QUIC are not done yet, expect rough edges and glitches. Enable verbose and keep attention to details

Happy http3ing!

```
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_3')) {
  define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_3', 30);
}
    
$ch = curl_init("https://cloudflare-quic.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_3);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I understand now. I tested it already and it worked, but forgot about updating. Thanks a lot. I see that libcurl in Ubuntu 19.10 is not compatible with HTTP/3, so I am sorry for mentioning that it is not possible in one of my comments.